# dynamic button event in xml parsing

Tags: wpf, xml-parsing

i create a dynamic button(xmlparsingbuildbutton) during a buttonclick(xmlparsingbutton) event.

I did a xml parsing...once each xml target is parsed, they will create an individual checkbox. What i need is this: Create a dynamic button event(xmlparsingbuildbutton). During this dynamic button event, for every checkbox that is checked, they will append a text file by writing new lines into the text file. This gets confusing to me because right now i have a foreachloop embedded in  the xmlparsingbutton event that creates all these checkboxes.

Right now, I've coded it in such a way that whenever i check the checkboxes, my append of file event will not fire therefore I created this "xmlparsingbuildbutton" to help fire the event.From my understanding, usually i would hard code buttonclickevent, however in this case the `target` value always change in the `foreach` loop and therefore it is not right to just merely hardcode the buttonclickevent.

So my question is how do i have this button event to be inside the `foreach` loop of the xmlparsing event button? Please clarify my doubts. Many thanks!

Here is my code:

```
private void xmlparsingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Build.xml");
    var abc = from target in xmlDoc.Descendants("target")
              select (string)target.Attribute("if");
    ColumnDefinition gridCol1 = new ColumnDefinition();
    gridCol1.Width = new GridLength(300);
    ColumnDefinition gridCol2 = new ColumnDefinition();
    gridCol2.Width = new GridLength(300);
    ColumnDefinition gridCol3 = new ColumnDefinition();
    gridCol3.Width = new GridLength(300);
    ColumnDefinition gridCol4 = new ColumnDefinition();
    gridCol4.Width = new GridLength(300);
    tab4grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1);
    tab4grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol2);
    tab4grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol3);
    tab4grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol4);
    RowDefinition gridRow1 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow1.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow2 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow2.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow3 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow3.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow4 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow4.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow5 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow5.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow6 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow6.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow7 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow7.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow8 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow8.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow9 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow9.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow10 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow10.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow11 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow11.Height = new GridLength(50);
    RowDefinition gridRow12 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRow12.Height = new GridLength(50);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow2);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow3);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow4);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow5);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow6);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow7);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow8);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow9);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow10);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow11);
    tab4grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow12);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    System.Windows.Controls.Button XmlparsingbuildButton = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
    Grid.SetColumn(XmlparsingbuildButton, 4);
    Grid.SetRow(XmlparsingbuildButton, 12);
    XmlparsingbuildButton.Height = 23;
    XmlparsingbuildButton.Width = 51;
    XmlparsingbuildButton.Content = "Build";
    tab4grid.Children.Add(XmlparsingbuildButton);
    foreach(string target in abc)
    {
        if (target != null && !Dictionarycheck.ContainsKey(target))
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox chk = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
            chk.Name = target+"CheckBox";
            chk.Content = target;
            Grid.SetColumn(chk, i); //sets column
            Grid.SetRow(chk, j); //sets row                    
            tab4grid.Children.Add(chk); //adds the control
            Tabitem5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            i++;
            if (i == 4)
            {
                j++;
                i = 0;
            }

            if (chk.IsChecked == true)
            {
                using (var writer = File.AppendText(@"c:\testing.txt"))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(target);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    Tabitem5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = 4;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit, I have problems understanding your problem. If I get it right, you're trying to do the following:

- Parse a Xml document ("C:\Build.xml") with (roughly) this format:

```
    targets>
      target if="aaa" />
      target if="bbb" />
   /targets>
```

- Create a CheckBox for each target tag with if- attribute set
- Check the CheckBox containing the string you want to use
- Click a button to append the checked strings to a text file ("c:\testing.txt")

If this is correct, then I think your solution won't do that. I not sure if I can understand what you are trying to do in your code. The way you set up the comboboxes they will never be checked the time you use your writer.

How about this:

- Use a StackPanel (stackPanel1) instead of a grid. That way you don't have to create all the row definitions. (Ok, I have to admit, I don't know what all these columns are for)
- Create a simple logic for a button to append the checked ComboBoxes to the file

code:

```
private void xmlparsingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  stackPanel1.Children.Clear();

  XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Build.xml");

  var abc = from target in xmlDoc.Descendants("target")
            select (string) target.Attribute("if");

  foreach (string target in abc)
  {
    if (target != null)
    {
      System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox chk = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
      chk.Name = target + "CheckBox";
      chk.Content = target;
      chk.Tag = target;
      stackPanel1.Children.Add(chk);
    }
  }
}

private void btnAppendToTextFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  using (var writer = File.AppendText(@"c:\testing.txt"))
  {
    foreach (var child in stackPanel1.Children)
    {
      if ((child is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox) child).IsChecked.Value)
      {
         writer.WriteLine(((CheckBox)child).Tag);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you with your problem.